# VSCode Python remove parenthesis while auto completing a class name

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When I try auto complete my Class name in vscode, the parenthesis also coming with Class name. How do I adjust the auto completion in vscode so that it should not auto complete parenthesis for class. But I still need the auto completion with functions as I need those params visible when calling. Or just auto complete after function/class name if I enter left parenthesis and press tab.
The last one would be better ;-)
Hopes someone has a solution for this :-)

Adding a GIF showing demo:
[image]

Comment: mine seems to does not do that, can you share an example?

Comment: @user_na added a demo in question end

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `JediLSP` Language Server? It also occurs to me.

I tried to find out some ways to configure it, but it was built in with the Python extension and seems the VSCode hasn't provided the methods to configure it.

After a switch to the `Pylance` Language Server, the problem solved.

Comment: I don't use separate `Pylance` provided by Microsoft in market. Only have the Python extension that have (`intelliScence Pylance`) and `Black` for formatting

Comment: Maybe you can take a try on it.

Comment: The Microsoft PyLance have issues with my django project, like it doesn't understand my django root. So it marks that yellow warning in all my imports. So I had to remove it and stay on Python Extension only.

Comment: Can you check these two links?
https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236;
https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings